Sample mean or James-Stein estimator?
I have a simple practical question, which I posted in Quant Finance SE (posting here as well, as I am not getting an answer(s) for it).
Suppose we have $n\geq3$ financial time series (correlated or uncorrelated) for stocks (e.g., 10 different time series of returns of $n$ stocks, each with $T$ observations). The goal is to estimate mean of each financial time series, i.e., $\hat{\mu}_{i}$, $i=1,2,...n$.
Apparently, the most straightforward approach would be to compute for each series sample mean, i.e., $\hat{\mu}_{i}=\frac{x_1+x_2+...x_T}{T}$, where $i=1,2,...n$. However, James-Stein estimator suggests that if $n\geq3$, then it is better to pool together all these $n$ financial time series, and then estimate mean vector collectively.
What approach would you use and why? In my knowledge, for such a simple problem all practitioners use the first approach (sample mean), and I don't know anyone who applied the second. Therefore, does it mean that this is due the fact that James-Stein is more a theoretical results, and it is hardly applicable or less preferred? If no, then why James-Stein is not used instead?

I think the James-Stein estimator is more of a theoretically interesting result -- it shows you can get improvement at no cost (in certain situations). If you don't really care about admissibility as a theoretical principle you wouldn't use it. And if you do really care about admissibility as a theoretical principle you also wouldn't use the James-Stein estimator, since it's not admissible.
However, it's quite common across statistics to use other shrinkage estimators for this sort of situation:

Bayesian estimators with hierarchical proper priors
random-effects estimators
L1 regularisation estimators related to the lasso

These are different from the James-Stein estimator in that they don't dominate the mean, but they do perform better that the mean if their explicit or implicit priors are well calibrated

Thanks a lot! In finance, specifically in portfolio management (Mean-Variance Optimization framework) JS estimator is rather commonly accepted, though never came across to any justification for it or effectiveness evaluation. Is JS estimator not admissible if $n \geq 3$ (I thought it is)? Also, could you please give references on the approaches suggested by you? Many thanks!

No, the JS estimator dominates the mean for $n\geq 3$ but is not itself admissible. It's dominated by the positive-part James-Stein estimator. And even that isn't admissible.
